# Detect if scrolled to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to detect if a div has scrolled to the bottom by using a button click function (not scroll arrow buttons)?

E.g.: So when `$('#checkBottom').` is clicked, if `$('#items')` has scrolled to the bottom of the div it outputs the alert. And when `$('#checkBottom').` is clicked, if `$('#items')` has not scrolled to the bottom of the div it dosen't output the alert.

Jq:

```
$('#checkBottom').on('click', function () {
    alert("yes, it has reached the bottom of the scroll");
});
```

scroll div structure example:

```
<div id="Wrapper">
    <div id="itemWrapper">
        <div id="items">
            <div class="content">
                <input type="image" src="http://img42.com/p1puE+" />
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <input type="image" src="http://img42.com/p1puE+" />
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <input type="image" src="http://img42.com/p1puE+" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _scrolled to the bottom of the div_? visible on the viewport or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport

Comment: Is `#checkBottom` positioned `fixed`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#checkBottom').on('click', function () {
  var wrapper = document.getElementById('Wrapper');
  if (wrapper.scrollTop + wrapper.offsetHeight >= wrapper.scrollHeight) {
    alert("yes, it has reached the bottom of the scroll");
  }
});
```